# Error illegal start of simple expression

Tags: scala, list, scala-collections, scalatest, for-comprehension

I am having this error :

> error: illegal start of simple expression
>   def process_alcs(lines: List[String]) : List[(String, Double)] = for (line <- lines) yield (val a = line.split(",")) (a[0],a[4].toDouble)

for this line of code :

```
def process_alcs(lines: List[String]) : List[(String, Double)] = 
  for (line <- lines) yield (val a = line.split(",")) (a[0],a[4].toDouble)
```

I first thought it was a parenthese mismatch but I checked 100 times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
 def process_alcs(lines: List[String]) : List[(String, Double)] = for (line <- lines) yield {
   val a = line.split(",")
   (a(0),a(4).toDouble)
 }
```

Basically, you are performing a multi line evaluation in your yield. As such, you must encapsulate the code in it with `{` instead of `(`. Also, both statements should be encapsulated in a single `{}` pair since they build up to what you want to yield.

Additionally, array members in scala are accessed using `()` and not `[]`. So, you want to use a(0) instead of a[0]

On a separate note, this seems related to another question someone else asked today in which case he wanted to convert to double the value in the 4th column. To access the 4th column, you would want to use a(3).

In that case, the code becomes,

```
def process_alcs(lines: List[String]) : List[(String, Double)] = for (line <- lines) yield {
  val a = line.split(",")
  (a(0), a(3).toDouble)
}
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any further questions :)

Edit: To convert to map, try,

```
def process_as_map(lines: List[String]) : Map[String, Double] = {
  val results: List[(String, Double)] = for (line <- lines) yield {
    val a = line.split(",")
    (a(0), a(3).toDouble)
  }
  results.toMap
}
```

Refer comments for explanation, on why I tweaked as such based on your code

Comment: I think it worked, thank you very much, but I have another issue. On my next function, I try to convert the values to push them in a map, I am doing :   def process_pops(lines: List[String]) : Map[String, Long] = for (line <- lines) yield {
  val b = line.split(",")
  (b(0) -> b(1).toLong).toMap
}                                                                                      which is not working. I started scala this week, thank you for your time

Comment: Moving the .toMap outside as such may help
`def process_pops(lines: List[String]): Map[String, Double] = {
  val results: List[(String, Double)] = for (line <- lines) yield {
    val a = line.split(",")
    (a(0), a(3).toDouble)
  }
  results.toMap
}`
When you call toMap on each individual tuple you build, you are converting each row to a map (with a single entry). Hence, you are left with a `List[Map[String, Double]]`. Instead if you switch to first building the entire `List[(String, Double)]` and then call `toMap` on that it would work as you expect

Comment: No problem. Good luck. Scala can have a tough initial curve. Its extremely rewarding once you get past that though.